# Can an object destroy itself?

Tags: c++, object, destroy

I have an object which needs to destroy itself.

- Can it be done?
- Is the example wrong?

  ```
  void Pawn::specialMoves(Coordinate const& from, Coordinate const& to, int passant)
  {
     /*...*/
      m_board->replace(to, new Queen(m_colour));//replace pawn by queen
  }

  void Board::replace(Coordinate const &to, Piece* newPiece)
  {
      delete tile[to.x()][to.y()];
      tile[to.x()][to.y()] = newPiece;
  }
  ```

Comment: What object is destroying itself here? FTR, destroying itself would be either `delete this;` or `this->~T();` (with `T` being its type). Both are valid but require lots of care to be used correctly.

Comment: I don't see anything destroying itself in your example.

Comment: Pawn deletes itself. I would imagine once `m_board->replace(to, new Queen(m_colour));` has been called function void Pawn::specialMoves(...)` can not finish `

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: The question was poorly worded. The pawn calls a method that in turn deletes the pawn. So, in effect, the pawn deletes itself.

Comment: It is a *very* common pattern in code that implements memory management with reference counting.  Count == 0 is harakiri.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Yes, it's legal to call `delete this` from inside a member function.  But there's **very** rarely a good reason to do so (especially if you're writing idiomatic C++ where most memory-management tasks should be delegated to containers, smart pointers, etc.).

And you need to be **very** careful:

- the suicide object must have been allocated dynamically via `new` (not `new[]`).
- once an object has committed suicide, it is undefined behaviour for it to do anything that relies on its own existence (it can no longer access its own member variables, call its own virtual functions, etc.).

Comment: A bit late here, but to make sure that an object was not allocated via `new[]`, would it suffice to write `operator new[]() = delete`?

Comment: I am assuming that calling `std` containers' removing methods is equally fine, amirite?

Answer (score 12):

Here's [a good sanity check for performing `delete this`](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/freestore-mgmt#delete-this).

Comment: Curious why the guidelines forbid this with placement new? Do they only mean that you can't `delete this` (since the object wasn't allocated via `new`), or that `this->~T();` is also forbidden?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it should work. Even `delete this;` is allowed.

But the code calling `specialMoves()` could be in for a nasty surprise.

Answer (score 1):

> Q: Can an object destroy itself?

A: Sure.  "delete this" is a popular idiom in COM/ActiveX

As far as your algorithm, I'd suggest:

- a "board" object has "tiles".  Perhaps just a simple 2-D array.
- You start out with n "pieces"
- Some controller (perhaps a "game" object), moves a "piece" with respect to a "tile".
- Each "tile" has a reference to 0 or 1 "pieces"

I'm not sure I see any reason to create or delete anything on a per-move basis.

IMHO...

Comment: I think the case is when the pawn reaches the opposite end of the board, it gets replaced by a queen.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't access member variables or the `this` pointer after the call to destroy the object, you should be fine.  Since it doesn't appear you're doing either of these things, the example should work.